# SSRS use Function in table header

Tags: function, reporting-services, tableheader

[image]

Hi,

Please see my table above, I would like to replace the table headers (Yesterday and Two Days Ago) with getdate()-1 and getdate()-2 to provide the date itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expressions in following:

**Yesterday**

```
=format(dateadd("d", -1, today()), "MMMM dd,yyyy")
```

**Two days ago**

```
=format(dateadd("d", -2, today()), "MMMM dd,yyyy")
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you.